# Handle losing connection

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurl

I download data from Internet in this way using Swift:

```
let postEndpoint: String = "http://webisitetest.com"
        guard let url = NSURL(string: postEndpoint) else {
            print("Error: cannot create URL")
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

        let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) in
            // this is where the completion handler code goes
            print(response)
            print(error)
        })

        task.resume()
```

Because I download also images and download can during various seconds (depends connection), if during download the user loses connection, how I do handle this situation?

I want to show him a message for example "Connection lost, download cancelled, try again", but how I do catch this event?

Answer (score 0):

Check for `error` presence in your completion handler:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(urlRequest, completionHandler: { (maybeData: NSData?, maybeResponse: NSURLResponse?, maybeError: NSError?) in
    // check for error
    guard maybeError = nil else {
        print(maybeError!)
    }

    // otherwise process the request
    print(maybeResponse)
})
```

Comment: when you say "check for error" You mean that there is a particular type of error for this kind of problem ?

Comment: Yes, any error will be represented as an object in completion handler.

Answer (score 0):

Any failure can be handled in the completion block. You can also specify the seconds before timeout for request and resource in the configuration.

```
- (NSURLSessionConfiguration*) requestConfigurations
{
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration ephemeralSessionConfiguration];

configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120;
configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 980.0;

return configuration;
}
```

Error codes from the error can help you distinguish the type of failure.